# Passing array to a function inside class PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question on how to pass an array to a function in PHP. I have a class called "MyClass" and inside it has functions called `rankVal($arr1, $arr2)` and `processResponse($data, $db, $id, $lat, $lng)`.

processResponse() will call rankVal() and here is my problem is.

```
class MyClass{
   private function cmpVal($a, $b){
        /*do sorting stuff*/
   }

   function rankVal($arr1, $arr2){
       $arrIdx=[];
       foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
           $n=array_search($value, $arr2);
           $newPos = ($key+$n)/2;
           $arrNewIdx [$n]=round($newPos,0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
       }

   }

   function processResponse($data, $db, $id, $lat, $lng){
       //Do some stuffs here...
       $someArr1 = [];
       foreach($results as $key => $value){
           $newVal = new stdClass();
           $newVal->key1 = $value->key1;
           $newVal->key2 = $value->key2;
           $newVal->key3 = $value->key3;
           $newVal->key4 = $value->key4;
           $newVal->key5 = $value->key5;
           $someArr1 []= $newVal;
       }
       $someArr2 = $someArr1;

       usort($someArr2, array($this, "cmpVal"));
       $rankedVal = $this->rankVal($someArr1, $someArr2);
   }
}
```

When I called the processResponse() function I got this error:
`array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

So, I `var_dump($arr2)` in `rankVal()`, and the output clearly says that $arr2 is an array. Here's the sample output of the `var_dump($arr2)`:

```
array(30) {
[0]=>
 object(stdClass)#385 (7) {
   ["key1"]=>
   string(24) "something"
   ["key2"]=>
   string(20) "something"
   ["key3"]=>
   string(41) "something"
   ["key4"]=>
   float(1.23455)
   ["key5"]=>
   float(1.19128371983198)
 }
```

What did I do wrong? I tried to pass the array by reference by adding "&" in `rankVal(&$arr1, &$arr2)`, but the error is still there.

Comment: *this will be array of objects*

Comment: @splash58 yes $arr1 and $arr2 are array of objects

Comment: array_search works with array not with object

Comment: @zangetsKid Given your code, the error message makes no sense. Please double check that if what you posted here is really what gives the error message. The only explanation currently would be that `$someArr1 = [/*this will be array of objects*/];` is not correct. Meaning `$someArr1` is an object to start with, and not a list of objects. Boiled down, your code is equvivalent to [this](https://3v4l.org/bNoMk), and there's no error message.

Comment: There you have it... it should be `$someArr1[] = $newVal;` not `$someArr1 = $newVal;`. (Also *equivalent ;))

Comment: @Yoshi actually that's what I meant..sorry I forgot to put '[]' after `$someArr1`

Comment: @zangetsKid Well then, my previous comment still stands, see the linked example. Given what you show here, the error message should not be encountered.

Comment: @Yoshi Yeah that's what I thought too..I shouldn't get this error..does using Slim PHP affect this?

Comment: I don't think so. There has to be some part of the code that actually changes the value of `$someArr2`. And I'd suspect that part of the code to be inside what you haven't posted here.

Comment: @Yoshi OK I found the problem..In the `rankVal()` function I called `usort()` but I used the same callback function `rankVal()`..So, it changed the value of `$someArr2`..Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear! You could write and accept your own answer, maybe it will help some future visitor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after checking my code again, I finally found the problem that causing this weird bug which was not supposed to be there.

The culprit is in the `rankVal()` function where I called `usort()` which used `rankVal()` as the callback function for the sorting process. Then, I changed this callback function to the right one, and voila problem's solved.

Thanks for everyone who had answered and given me some suggestions on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> To add to the other answer here (which now seems to have gone), if you want your class to behave as an array where appropriate, you need to make it iterable.

All you need to do is implement [Iterable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).  This means that you need to create the necessary methods, but this is all you need in order to have your class behave that way.

Its useful for classes which are designed to hold an array of data, but you want to encapsulate additional tools along with that data.

Heres an example:

```
class Row implements \Iterator {
    protected $data;
    protected $position = 0;

    public function __construct( array $data = [ ]) {
        $this->data = $data;

    }

    public function addData( $value ) {
        $this->data[] = $value;
    }

    public function replaceData( $index, $value ) {

        $this->data[ $index ] = $value;
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData( array $data ) {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    /** Required by Iterator */
    public function current() {
        return $this->data[ $this->position ];
    }

    /** Required by Iterator */
    public function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    public function __toArray() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    /** Required by Iterator */
    public function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /** Required by Iterator */
    public function valid( $index = null ) {
        return isset( $this->data[ $index ? $index : $this->position ] );
    }

    /** Required by Iterator */
    public function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function count() {
        return count( $this->data );
    }

}
```

Once you have this, it can be used anywhere you can use an array.